# linux bash cut one row which starts with a certain string

Tags: linux, bash

Good day,

im using linux bash commands to extract certain data of each sip account and put them next to each other.

i have an array called $peers that i put all 1000 sips into and now i need to for loop through them to set every sip to its useragent.

what i have so far is

```
#! /bin/bash

peers="$(asterisk -rx "sip show peers" | cut -f1 -d" " | cut -f1 -d"/" "=")" "= "  asterisk -rx "sip show peer " $peer | cut -f2 -d"Useragent"

for peer in  $peers do
echo $peers
done

#echo $peers
```

I need to extract a row from a collection of rows that starts with "Useragent"

I start by running `asterisk -rx "sip show peer 101"` and that gives me the result below

```
* Name       : 101
  Description  :
  Secret       : <Set>
  MD5Secret    : <Not set>
  Remote Secret: <Not set>
  Context      : outgoing
  Record On feature : automon
  Record Off feature : automon
  Subscr.Cont. : <Not set>
  Language     :
  Tonezone     : <Not set>
  AMA flags    : Unknown
  Transfer mode: open
  CallingPres  : Presentation Allowed, Not Screened
  Callgroup    :
  Pickupgroup  :
  Named Callgr :
  Nam. Pickupgr:
  MOH Suggest  :
  Mailbox      :
  VM Extension : asterisk
  LastMsgsSent : 0/0
  Call limit   : 0
  Max forwards : 0
  Dynamic      : Yes
  Callerid     : "" <>
  MaxCallBR    : 384 kbps
  Expire       : 23
  Insecure     : no
  Force rport  : Yes
  Symmetric RTP: Yes
  ACL          : No
  DirectMedACL : No
  T.38 support : No
  T.38 EC mode : Unknown
  T.38 MaxDtgrm: -1
  DirectMedia  : Yes
  PromiscRedir : No
  User=Phone   : No
  Video Support: No
  Text Support : No
  Ign SDP ver  : No
  Trust RPID   : No
  Send RPID    : No
  Subscriptions: Yes
  Overlap dial : Yes
  DTMFmode     : rfc2833
  Timer T1     : 500
  Timer B      : 32000
  ToHost       :
  Addr->IP     : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5060
  Defaddr->IP  : (null)
  Prim.Transp. : UDP
  Allowed.Trsp : UDP
  Def. Username: 101
  SIP Options  : (none)
  Codecs       : (gsm|ulaw|alaw|g729|g722)
  Codec Order  : (gsm:20,g722:20,g729:20,ulaw:20,alaw:20)
  Auto-Framing :  No
  Status       : OK (9 ms)
  Useragent    : UniFi VoIP Phone 4.6.6.489
  Reg. Contact : sip:101@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5060;ob
  Qualify Freq : 60000 ms
  Keepalive    : 0 ms
  Sess-Timers  : Accept
  Sess-Refresh : uas
  Sess-Expires : 1800 secs
  Min-Sess     : 90 secs
  RTP Engine   : asterisk
  Parkinglot   :
  Use Reason   : No
  Encryption   : No
```

Now i need to cut this part `Useragent    : UniFi VoIP Phone 4.6.6.489`

and display it as `101 : UniFi VoIP Phone 4.6.6.489`

any help would be much appreciated

Thank you. that top answer worked perfectly. this is my solution now.

```
peer="$(asterisk -rx "sip show peers" | cut -f1 -d" " | cut -f1 -d"/" )"


for peer in  $peers do

output= "$(asterisk -rx "sip show peer $peers" | sed -nE '/Useragent/ s/^[^:]+/101 /p')"
echo $output


done
```

But is is still giving issue, my problem is the loop of the variables

Comment: Capturing the output just so you can `echo` it is a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo).  Regardless, you should put the variable in double quotes unless you specifically require the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
... | sed -nE '/Useragent/ s/^[^:]+/101 /p'
```

- `/Useragent/` matches line(s) with `Useragent` it
- `s/^[^:]+/101` substitutes the portion from start till `:` (exclusive) with `101`

Comment: With regards to my bash script, i am having some trouble with my looping through the sips, would you mind telling me what is wrong with my loop? i have updated my question with the new script as i have it with your answer included

Comment: @AndreaVisnenzaAndy Not sure what you are trying to do bu in `bash` variable declaration can't have any whitespace around `=`. DO: `output=$(asterisk -rx "sip show peer $peers" | sed -nE '/Useragent/ s/^[^:]+/101 /p')`

Comment: Thanks :) in the first variable $peers i am adding about 2000 numbers, each looking like "1000" "1001" "1002" now i want to use that variable in a 4 loop to loop through each one and output the second argument